# Xcode 5 unsupported architecture

Tags: architecture, xcode5

I am trying to build an app in Xcode 5.1 and anytime I try to run it on a device or simulator then Xcode tells me that I need to "Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device". I have tried what you see online including

- Checking for multiple info.plist
- Make sure the compiler is the standard llvm 5.1
- Cleaning the project
- Restarting Xcode and computer
- Setting architecture to arm64, arm7, armv7s

One thing I have noticed in that most of the problems are related to the Facebook API/SDK which I am not using. Please tell me any other code/settings that I should post. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does a brand new single view application run on your simulator and/or device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
>
Go to Target -> Build setting and do the following steps

1.Select Architectures-> click on others and add $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)

2.Select valid Architectures ->add armv7 ,armv7s,arm64

3.Build Options "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" -> Set "Default compiler (Apple LLVM 5.1)"